# Would the IS site be an appropriate place to ask for help in deciding between a Masters in Cyber Security vs a CISSP certification?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

Before I posted, I wanted to make sure it would be acceptable? If not, is there a better site I could look for advice from the community?

Answer (score 7):

This is the type of question that we get a lot of, and they tend to get closed as opinion-based. Unless there is a very specific, factual question you want to ask.

Without knowing what your question actually is, the problem is likely to be that your question is going to depend on your personal history, experience and skills, dependent on the employers in your areas, dependent on the content and quality of the degree, and a guess about the future. And from experience in these types of questions, it is likely also going to depend on the type of cybersecurity that you want to get into, which most people are not clear about.

Again, without knowing what you want to ask, in my experience, the answer people *need* about these types of questions is to perform **informational interviews** with the employers in your area. You get a degree or a certification to use to get a new job, and only your target employers can advise you on what makes sense to them.

It's the ambiguity of the above things that makes it difficult to answer and results in people guessing at an answer.

If you feel that your question avoids the ambiguity, feel free to ask.

Aside from discussion forums, I know of no StackExchange site that would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the detailed feedback. Let me see if I can add some more meat/context to the question.